# Encrypt a string in .NET and decrypt it in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross platform (php to C# .NET) encryption/decryption with Rijndael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329260/cross-platform-php-to-c-net-encryption-decryption-with-rijndael)

How can I encrypt something in .NET and decrypt it in PHP?

Comment: It's not clear, what you mean by "best". You can use any two-way encryption algorithm for which there exists an implementation in PHP and C#...

Comment: You should never encrypt passwords with an technology that lets you decrypt it again.

Comment: @Daniel , Hi can u sugesst two way algorithm that can be used for encrypting in .net and decrypting using php

Comment: @Jannis: I don't agree. There are several use cases where you need to decrypt the passwords. For example: You store the password to your database in the config file. One way encryption won't help you here.

Comment: @user690932: No, I don't use PHP

Comment: what about using RC4, its two way & widely used can be adapted to any lang. i have an example if you want to see

Comment: I don't see why the language matters. Everything that you encrypt in .NET can be decrypted in PHP as long as you have the key and a correct implementation of the algorithm you used to encrypt. What is your actual question? Is it which algorithm to use?

Answer (score 6):

You can encrypt/decrypt cross-platform using the TripleDES symmetric encryption algorithm.

This URL provides a working sample:
[PHP and C# common encryption and decryption function class, Use of 3DES encryption and decryption](http://blog.950buy.com/article/php-and-net-common-encryption-and-decryption-function-class-use-of-3des-encryption-and-decryption/)

Comment: This link is now spam, and I suspect it's trying to install a malicious Chrome Extension.